# Changing order of 2 cell values on condition (Pandas,Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im scanning on my pandas dataframe that look like:

| Price | Price/sqft | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1m | 1000 | CA |
| **2000m** | **2** | PA |
| 3m | 3000 | CA |
| 4m | 4000 | CA |

Whenever cell 'price' and 'price/sqft' got switch up in dataframe => I have to switch it back, all of the input are tuple and I want price/sqft only in numeric format.

```
Price/sqft=''.join(map(str, PM))
Price=''.join(map(str, MT))

try:
  df['Price/sqft'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price/sqft'])
except:
  df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'])
  df.loc['Price','Price/sqft'] = (df.loc['Price/sqft','Price'].values)
```

The code give error like

```
 in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Price/sqft'
```

Comment: the column name has price spelled with a lowercase p, while in your code, you spelled it with capital

Comment: Did that not solves your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not that is only forum posting error, my dataframe dictionary is all good.

Comment: Perhaps you should try `df[['Price','Price/sqft']] = df[['Price/sqft','Price']].values` instead of `.loc`